# Uninitialized local variable - No error : Java

Tags: java, initialization, local-variables, main-method

Here are two uninitialized local variables. Still this does not give compile time or runtime error and executes completely. Is this thing permissible in Java and How (explanation will be welcome).

```
class A2{ }

public class A {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x;
    A2 a2;

    System.out.println("Main");
}

}
```

Comment: I have read "Always initialized a local variable" "A uninitialized local variable violates the java rules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing incorrect about that code. You don't actually use those variables so there's no issue. If you did try to use them it would then become a problem. For example,

```
System.out.println(a2);
System.out.println(x);
```

would bring about "Variable 'x'/'a2' might not have been intitialized" errors. There will be no default values or ability to run the code. It will be a compile time error and your code won't run. If the variables were class fields they would get default values for certain types or `null` otherwise.

Comment: If in this code x is getting a default value , then can I print this value?

Comment: In this what value will they get. I am not using them. Would they hold some thing in stack when this code is written?

Answer (score 0):

Both variables are not used in code. Once you try to use it as  System.out.println("Main" + x); It will give you compilation error as local variable is not initialized.

Comment: In this what value will they get. I am not using them. Would they hold some thing in stack when this code is written?

Comment: @IDontKnow006 As you can never observe that value, the question is pointless. It's even possible that the variables are removed completely.

Comment: @EJP I didn't got your that statement - It's even possible ........ removed completely."

Comment: @IDontKnow006 You didn't get what about it? It seems clear to me. An unused local variable contributes nothing at runtime and is an obvious candidate for being 'optimized' away.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, local variable declarations you have done in the above code is allowed as long as you don't access them. If you happen to write any code that access those variables, the code will not compile.

According to Java Language Specification, you can't access local variables (the variables that you declare inside a method) unless they are initialized before accessing. Below is from Java Language Specification for SE 8.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4.1

**Chapter 16 - Definite Assignment**

"For every access of a local variable or blank final field x, x must be definitely
assigned before the access, or a compile-time error occurs."

**Chapter 14**

14.4.2 Execution of Local Variable Declarations
A local variable declaration statement is an executable statement. Every time it is
executed, the declarators are processed in order from left to right. If a declarator
has an initializer, the initializer is evaluated and its value is assigned to the variable.
***If a declarator does not have an initializer, then every reference to the variable must be
preceded by execution of an assignment to the variable, or a compile-time error occurs by
the rules of §16 (Definite Assignment).***
Each initializer (except the first) is evaluated only if evaluation of the preceding
initializer completes normally.
Execution of the local variable declaration completes normally only if evaluation
of the last initializer completes normally.
If the local variable declaration contains no initializers, then executing it always
completes normally.

Answer (score 0):

you will get a compile-time error once you start using uninitialized local variables. For example:

**Case 1: No error**

```
public static void doJob(int[] a){
    
   int temp;   
}
```

**Case 2: Gives error**

```
 public static void doJob(int[] a){
    
    int temp;
    System.out.println(temp);    
}
```